# assigning a main id to observations that appear more than once

Tags: r

I have a dataset where a person can appear more than once. `id1` is a vector of unique IDs that are assigned. Some people get two unique IDs because they appear more than once. `id2` lists someone's alias.

Have:

```
have <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                   id2 = c(4, NA, 6, NA, 7, NA, NA))

have

#  id1 id2
#1   1   4
#2   2  NA
#3   3   6
#4   4  NA
#5   5   7
#6   6  NA
#7   7  NA
```

I want to create a new variable `id` that is the reconciled id.

Want:

```
#  id1 id2  id
#1   1   4   1
#2   2  NA   2
#3   3   6   3
#4   4  NA   1
#5   5  NA   7
#6   6  NA   3
#7   7   5   5
```

Comment: Why row 7 is 5 in `ìd` column?

Comment: sorry about that. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? (didn't catch the exact logic for generating `id`)

```
transform(
  have,
  id = replace(id1,na.omit(id2),id1[!is.na(id2)])
)
```

which gives

```
  id1 id2 id
1   1   4  1
2   2  NA  2
3   3   6  3
4   4  NA  1
5   5  NA  7
6   6  NA  3
7   7   5  7
```

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
have %>%
 mutate(id = coalesce(id1[match(id1, id2)], id1))

  id1 id2 id
1   1   4  1
2   2  NA  2
3   3   6  3
4   4  NA  1
5   5  NA  7
6   6  NA  3
7   7   5  7
```